# Scope that includes subflows of a flow, but not its "parent flow"?

Tags: spring-webflow

Suppose that flow A has subflow B, which in turn has subflow C.  Is there a scope that would be visible in B and C, but not in A?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an obj to be visible in Subflow C (from subflow B) You could just pass the pojo/obj DIRECTLY from Subflow B -> Subflow C via params using 'input' and 'output' tags and avoid using scopes all together.

See this post for an example:

[Spring Flow: Pass object back and forth from between Main WebFlow and Subflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885951/spring-flow-pass-object-back-and-forth-from-between-main-webflow-and-subflow)